# UInable to enter values in a textbox after applyting Inner shade effects in wpf using mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In my sample WPF-MVVM application , ihave one textbox and i have applied some Inner shade effects like this

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="TxtBoxStyle">     
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,4" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Grid x:Name="txtgrid">
                        <Border x:Name="txtBorder" CornerRadius="5" Background="LightGray" BorderBrush="DarkGray" 
       BorderThickness="1" ClipToBounds="True">
                            <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black" 
          BorderThickness="1" Margin="-2">
                                <Border.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="5" BlurRadius="10"/>
                                </Border.Effect>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>                        
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

But after applying these effects I am unable to enter values in textbox.

Please let me know whether my code is correct or not.

Answer (score 3):

You have replaced the default template, but not provided anywhere to display the content. Your template only contains `Borders`.

If you take a look at the [default TextBox template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can see that it defines a named part called `PART_ContentHost` that takes the content. Try adding that to your template.

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when i have added the ScrollViewer tag , I got error as The object 'Border' already has a child and cannot add 'ScrollViewer'. 'Border' can accept only one child. Please let me this error.

Comment: Please post your new template xaml

Comment: hi I am unable to send that code. Is it possible to chat with you.